# Best way to denote tuples and sets?

Tags: notation

When writing a research paper, what is the best way to denote a tuple and a set?
The problem is the following: I have a set of geometric intersections $\{s_1,s_2,s_3,...\}$ and then I order them. So I can say that I have a tuple of intersections $(s_1,s_2,s_3,...)$.

First I though it might be good to denote the set by $\mathbf{s}$ (bolded math s) and the tuple by $\vec s$, but then I though it might be strange to use vectors since I'm not dealing with vector spaces. Any thoughts what might be a natural (or most often used) choice or letters? I need a single letter, since I'm using the sequences as indices later.

Comment: Your notation seems good. If you introduce it properly, there's no need to worry about its possible misinterpretations.

Comment: This seems alright. As Berci said: as long as you make clear what your notation means there should be no confusion. Another common notation for tuples is just a bar, so $\bar{s}$. That would have no chance of being confused with a vector.

Comment: I see no technical problem with your notation, though I do find it unaesthtic---I really don't like the $\vec{s}$ notation.  Personally, I like to use capital letters for sets and bold letters for tuples or vectors (should the distinction be necessary).  Thus, $S = \{s_j\}$, and $\mathbf{s} = (s_j)$.  I also like @MarkKamsma's suggestion:  $s$ for the set, $\bar{s}$ for the ordered set.